# SAS - Text Parsing for Case Sensitive Characters

Tags: sas, text-parsing

Im having some problems cleaning up free form text strings from a series of notations. The last part of this task involves identifying any names, and removing them from the string. Luckily, all names are U-Cased (always), and the relevant information is placed before the name (always).

My first thought was to use the FIND function to isolate where the name starts, then just output all characters before the starting position...but I could not determine how to use a "wild card" like option to grab the starting position of ANY capital letter. Sample and attempts included below -

```
DATA SAMPLE;
INPUT TXT $;
CARDS;
firsT 
Second
thIrd 
foUrth
;
RUN;
```

Attempt1:

```
DATA TEST;
SET SAMPLE;
ID = FIND(TXT,'A'-'Z');
RUN;
```

Attempt2:

```
DATA TEST;
SET SAMPLE;
ID = FIND(TXT,'A-Z');
RUN;
```

Clearly both attempts above are not too far from one another, but I could not find (or think) of another approach. Hoping that some mysterious function will come to rescue here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want to do, you're close - just not doing things the 'SAS' way.

`FIND` has two siblings, `FINDC` and `FINDW`.  [`FINDC`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1mdh2gvd5potjn14jipysvzn4o7.htm) finds a single character in a list of characters, which it sounds like what you want to do.  It has a lot of options for adding lists of characters; you can't just give it `A-Z` as that would add those three characters, but you can give it a `U` option to add uppercase characters.

```
DATA TEST;
  SET SAMPLE;
  _endpos= FINDC(TXT,,'u');
  ID = substr(TXT,1,_endpos-1);
RUN;
```

Comment: This IS the function I was looking for! Just need to confirm...since people have names that could begin with any letter...I assume the null reference ",," after specifying your source (TXT in this case) is the "wild card" flavor that I need?

Comment: The null reference is to the explicit list of characters. IE findc(txt,,'u') is equivalent to findc(txt,'ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'). You can combine the optional third argument with other single characters if you want (like a space or a dash or similar).

Comment: You can probably tell that the last two questions (this and the previous one you answered for me) are part of the same task. I have a question that's also related to this task...how would I find a condition of two capital letters(non explicit) in a row within a string? Should I be posting this as a separate question?